# как заполнить в quartus 15.0 инструкциями файл .he

Tags: процессор

[image: задание, которое нужно выполнить, пункт 45]

Нужна помощь с 45 пунктом, никак не могу понять как заполнять этот файл?

[image: мой файл INSTR.hex]
у меня файл выглядит следующим образом, есть некоторые инструкции (фото 3) которыми и нужно заполнить этот файл. Может есть кто понимает в этом?

[image: инструкции]